# How to properly use std::functional for other data types (in priority queue)

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I'm currently stumbling upon the class like std::greater, std::lesser,etc from std::functional.

As you can see, those class are with <> so that they could be used with any data type.
So, I tried to make those class "properly" recognize the order by overloading the bool operator.

However, this is what I tried and did not work properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass(int x, std::string str) {(*this).x = x; (*this).str = str;}
        int getInt()const{return (*this).x;}
        std::string getStr(){return this->str;}
        bool operator <(const MyClass& ot)const{return (*this).getInt() < ot.getInt();}
        bool operator >(const MyClass& ot)const{return (*this).getInt() > ot.getInt();}
    private:
        int x;
        std::string str;
};
int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<MyClass*,std::vector<MyClass*>,std::less<MyClass*> > MinQ;
    std::priority_queue<MyClass*,std::vector<MyClass*>,std::greater<MyClass*> > MaxQ;
    MyClass *m = new MyClass(1,"one");
    MinQ.push(m); MaxQ.push (m);
    m = new MyClass(36,"thirty six");
    MinQ.push(m); MaxQ.push (m);
    m = new MyClass(47,"forty six");
    MinQ.push(m); MaxQ.push (m);
    m = new MyClass(1,"first");
    MinQ.push(m); MaxQ.push (m);
    m = new MyClass(2,"second");
    MinQ.push(m); MaxQ.push (m);
    m = new MyClass(2,"two");
    MinQ.push(m); MaxQ.push (m);
    m = new MyClass(7,"seven");
    MinQ.push(m); MaxQ.push (m);
    m = new MyClass(28,"twenty eight");
    MinQ.push(m); MaxQ.push (m);

    while(!MinQ.empty())
    {
        std::cout<<MinQ.top()->getStr()<<std::endl; MinQ.pop();
    }
    std::cout<<"------------------------------------------------"<<std::endl;
    while(!MaxQ.empty())
    {
        std::cout<<MaxQ.top()->getStr()<<std::endl; MaxQ.pop();
    }

}
```

The results:

```
twenty eight
seven
two
second
thirty six
forty six
first
one
------------------------------------------------
one
first
forty six
thirty six
second
two
seven
twenty eight
```

Can someone give me the explanation about this and/or give me the advice towards the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use pointers in your data structures and not objects.

You have two solutions : either you write a functor that works on pointers :

```
struct Greater
{
    bool operator()(MyClass *a, MyClass *b) const
    {
        return *a > *b;
    }
};

std::priority_queue<MyClass*,std::vector<MyClass*>, Greater > MaxQ;
```

Either you work directry with objects (I would very strongly recommend this approach, but it is not always appliable).

```
std::priority_queue<MyClass,std::vector<MyClass>, std::less<MyClass> > MinQ;
```